# Can I create or generate an invalid System.Guid in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, guid

Can somehow an invalid System.Guid object be created in .Net (Visual Basic or C#).  I know about Guid.Empty method but it is not what I am searching for. For example with invalid symbols or spaces or being too short or longer than an valid one etc. 
Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at guid.tryparse

Comment: Thanks, Alex. What I need is not to test if a Guid is valid or not but if I am able to create an invalid one and pass it as method argument in a Unit Test for example.

Comment: Ah, well if it were invalid it could not be of type Guid, I think empty or all set FFF-FFFF.. are your only options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can a Guid be created with invalid symbols or spaces or being too short or longer than an valid one etc?

No - a Guid is just a 128-bit number that can be *represented* in 5 groups of hexadecimal numbers.  There's no way for the string representation of a `Guid` to contain anything other than 32 hex characters (and possibly 4 hyphens or a few other formatting characters).

You can create a *string* that does not represent a valid `Guid`, but there's no way to put that into a `Guid` object.

Comment: Thanks, @D.Stanley. This is a conclusion that i also reached after some reading on the subject.

Comment: I think you mean 4 dashes (not 3)

Comment: @bytedev Thanks, I was off-by-one in my counting :). fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this using the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for Guid:

```
Guid badGuid = new Guid("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz");
```

If this throws an exception then it means the runtime will not allow you to construct an invalid Guid, and you don't need to test for that scenario. Note that according to the docs it must be given the correct number of characters, so that case is definitely not testable. On a different note, are you sure you're testing the behavior of your code, because it sounds like you're trying to write tests for extremely specific framework features which is not the purpose of unit testing your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Guid.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

```
string[] guids = { "cd334e7e-7370-4d2f-8276-25d08e582da7", "Foo" };
Guid newGuid;
foreach (string guidString in guids)
{
    if (Guid.TryParse(guidString, out newGuid))
        Console.WriteLine("Converted {0} to a Guid", guidString);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert {0} to a Guid", guidString);
}
```

Output:

```
Converted cd334e7e-7370-4d2f-8276-25d08e582da7 to a Guid
Unable to convert Foo to a Guid
```

**Edit**: "What I need is not to test if a Guid is valid or not but if I am able to create an invalid one and pass it as method argument in a Unit Test for example."

So you need to find a way to pass an "invalid" `Guid` to a method. I would suggest to use a `Nullable<Guid>` instead.

```
public static void Foo(Guid? guid)
{
    if (guid.HasValue)
    {
        Guid g = guid.Value;
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now you can use this method in these ways:

```
Foo(null);                  // will be a Guid? without a value
Foo(new Nullable<Guid>());  // will be a Guid? without a value
Foo(Guid.NewGuid());
Foo(Guid.Empty);
Foo(guidVariable);
```

Comment: Note, though, that Guid.TryParse was only added in .NET 4.0.

Comment: What is the sense here, @Tim? Guid.NewGuid() creates a valid Guid for sure and you try to test if it is valid. I want to know can I create or generate an invalid Guid and use it as method argument in unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

What does invalid mean to you? That's defined by what your code can deal with. A `Guid` is just 16 arbitrary bytes without any mandatory format. *You* define what kinds of `Guid` you want to accept.

In that sense any `Guid` object is valid by itself. There's no invalid state for this struct.

It is like an `int`. Any `int` is valid.

Comment: And that's why nullable types were introduced.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm not getting your comment. Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Maybe. I guess OP needs a way to pass an "invalid" Guid to differentiate between a Guid that must be processed and one that does not need to be processed/in a different way. Perhaps i've read too much into the question.